# Number of functions verifying $f(f(x))=f(x)$.

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Find the number of functions $f:\{1,2,3,4\}\to \{1,2,3,4\}$ that verify $f(f(x))=f(x)$. I'm not sure if the answer is $41$ or $29$.

Comment: Note that the condition implies that $f$ is the identity on its image. Now you can count amongst all different images.

Comment: Why don't you add the reasoning you used to arrive at the two figures 41 and 29 to your post? That way other users can help you fix your own reasoning, rather than supply reasoning for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to enumerate them based on the number of fixed points.

If you have $4$ fixed points, $f$ is the identity. So there's only one possibility.

If you have $3$, the one left can't be mapped to itself. So we have ${4\choose 3}\cdot 3$ possibilities.

If you have $2$, we'll call the ones left $i,j$. If $f(i)=j$ then $f(j)=f(f(i))=f(i)=j$, which is wrong since $j$ isn't a fixed point. So they're both mapped to the fixed points. ${4\choose 2}\cdot2\cdot2$ possibilities.

If you have one fixed point. By the same reasoning, all of the others map to it. ${4\choose 1}$ possibilities.

The final result is: $1+12+24+4=41$

Answer (score 4):

A function satisfying $f(f(x))=f(x)$ is called *idempotent*, and such functions, as Marc said in a comment, are the identity on their image (i.e., if $y\in\operatorname{im} f$ then $f(y)=y$).

Every subset of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is possible as an image of $f$ (and there are $2^4=16$ of these), so we must count the number of possible ways of obtaining such images.  If the image is a one-element set, then there are four options, the four constant functions.  If the image is a two-element set, then there are two elements which aren't fixed and there are four possible options for them.  If the image is a three-element set, then the fourth element has three possible images, and if the image is a four-element set, then the identity function is the only option.  Thus, the number is
$$4 + 4\binom{4}{2} + 3\binom{4}{3} + 1=41.$$

In fact, we can generalize this to $\sum_{i=1}^ni^{n-i}\binom{n}{i}$ for a function $f:\{1,\dots,n\}\to\{1,\dots,n\}$.  There are $\binom{n}{i}$ subsets of an $n$-element set, and for each set the remaining $n-i$ elements can map to any of the $i$ fixed elements in that set.

Comment: Good approach to attack the problem

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ maps it's image to itself, any number in the image must come from itself. Now count:

There is only a single number in $f(x)$. This gives four options: $1111, 2222 ...$

Only two numbers in the output. Two numbers are determined, and the rest can be anything. Thus we have another:
$${4 \choose 2} \cdot 2^2 = 24$$
Options.

If there are three numbers in the output we have:
$${4\choose 3}\cdot 3 = 12$$
More options. Add the identity map to these to get:

$$41$$