# Number of functions such that f(f(x)) = f(f(f(x))

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I have been working on this problem recently:

> The number of functions $f(x)$ from {$1, 2, 3, 4, 5$} to {$1, 2, 3, 4, 5$} that satisfy $$f(f(f(x))) = f(f(x))$$ $\forall x \in$ {$1, 2, 3, 4, 5$} is ?

Though I have been through a variant of this problem asked in this question:
[Number of functions verifying $f(f(x))=f(x)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1251797/number-of-functions-verifying-ffx-fx),
and I have also become acquainted with the graph theoretic approach of the same question asked at
[Number of functions such that $f(f(f(x)))=f(f(x))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4093446/number-of-functions-such-that-fffx-ffx), while solving this problem in a class, our instructor said there must be at least one ***$(x,x)$*** mapping in the function to satisfy the condition given, where $x \in${$1, 2, 3, 4, 5$}.

He then proceeded to take cases of when there are $1, 2, 3, 4,$ and $5$ respectively of such pairs in our mapping, summing these cases to get $756$, which is the final answer.

What I could not acquaint myself with, nor find an explanation for online was why this statement (at least one $(x,x)$ mapping) is true. I could very well be lacking in my research, so it would be greatly appreciated if you could link a resource that explains this (or other variants of the problem).

Comment: Not sure what an $(x,x)$ mapping is. Just guessing:  if you mean there must be a fixed point for $f$ (some value $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)=x_0$), then that's clear.  the entire image of $f\circ f$ is fixed by $f$.  If you meant something else, please edit to clarify.

Comment: @lulu, yes that's what I meant by an (x, x) mapping, that for some x in the original set f(x) = x

Comment: Ok, and is my proof clear?

Comment: I'm sorry but it isn't, I couldn't understand what you meant by 'the entire image' being fixed.

Comment: Let $i\in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and let $j=f\circ f(i)$ (of course $i$ could equal $j$ or not).  $j$, of course, is in the image of $f\circ f$.  Then your equation reads $j=f(j)$ so $j$ is a fixed point for $f$.

Comment: Oh yes that makes sense now. It now seems a trivial thing to ask in the first place, thank you for clarifying!

Comment: Out of curiosity, can the inverse function on both sides to give $f(f(x))=f(x)$?

Comment: @TymaGaidash We're not told that the function is invertible, so this may not be possible.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Indeed the only invertible function with this property is the identity (because you could apply the inverse a second time to get $f(x) = x$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $i \in \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ and let $j = f \circ f(i)$. Then your equation tells us $f(j) = j$, so $j$ is a fixed point for $f$. Therefore $f$ certainly has at least one fixed point.

(Community Wiki because this received a satisfactory answer in the comments from someone who isn't me.)